# Issue with Gradient Tape in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to implement a U-Net with region proposal network in tensorflow. I have a keras model that compiles, but when I try to write a training loop with GradientTape() I get the "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:" error. This appears to be a fairly common issue with a variety of causes, and I'm struggling to figure out what the cause is in this case.

Here is the function where I define my model (with various blocks defined outside the function):

```
def get_UNet_RPN(params): 
    n_filters=params['n_filters']
    batchnorm=params['batchnorm']
    attention=params['attention']
    imh=params['imh']
    imw=params['imw']
    input_img=Input(shape=(imh,imw,3))
    c1 = conv2d_block(input_img, n_filters=n_filters*1, c1=True, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)
    #p1 = Dropout(dropout*0.5)(p1)
    
    c2 = conv2d_block(p1, n_filters=n_filters*2, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)
    #p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)
    
    c3 = conv2d_block(p2, n_filters=n_filters*4, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)
    #p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)
    
    c4 = conv2d_block(p3, n_filters=n_filters*8, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)
    #p4 = Dropout(dropout)(p4)
    
    c5 = conv2d_block(p4, n_filters=n_filters*16, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    
    # expansive path
    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    if attention:
        c4 = att_block(c4, c5, n_filters=n_filters*8, kernel_size=2, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    #u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters=n_filters*8, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    
    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    if attention:
        c3 = att_block(c3, c6, n_filters=n_filters*4, kernel_size=2, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    #u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
    c7 = conv2d_block(u7, n_filters=n_filters*4, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    
    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
    if attention:
        c2 = att_block(c2, c7, n_filters=n_filters*2, kernel_size=2, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    #u8 = Dropout(dropout)(u8)
    c8 = conv2d_block(u8, n_filters=n_filters*2, c1=False, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    
    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
    if attention:
        c1 = att_block(c1, c8, n_filters=n_filters*1, kernel_size=2, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    #u9 = Dropout(dropout)(u9)
    c9 = conv2d_block(u9, n_filters=n_filters*1, c1=False,  kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    
    UNet_out = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
    # Define RPN
    scales=params['scales']
    ratios=params['ratios']
    input_height=params['imh']
    input_width=params['imw']
    feat_map=p4 #change this to alter where RPN input gets pulled 
    feat_map_shape=tf.shape(feat_map)
    feat_map_shape=tf.cast(feat_map_shape,tf.float64)
    num_ref_anchors = scales.shape[0] * ratios.shape[0]
    rpn = Conv2D(512, (3, 3),activation="relu", padding="same", name="rpn_conv/3x3")(feat_map)
    # This is the score to determine an anchor is foreground vs background
    rpn_cls_score = Conv2D(num_ref_anchors, [1, 1], activation='sigmoid',
                            padding='valid', name='rpn_cls_score')(rpn)

    # change it so that the score has 2 as its channel size
    rpn_cls_score_reshape = tf.reshape(rpn_cls_score, [-1, 2])
    # Now the shape of rpn_cls_score_reshape is (H * W * num_anchors, 4)
    rpn_cls_prob = Softmax()(rpn_cls_score_reshape)
    # rpn_bbox_pred has shape (?, H, W, num_anchors * 4)
    rpn_bbox_pred = Conv2D(num_ref_anchors * 4, [1, 1],
                            (1, 1), activation="linear", name='rpn_bbox_pred')(rpn)

    # Generate segmentation mask
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(UNet_out, axis=3)
    pred_mask = tf.reshape(pred_mask,[input_height,input_width])
    pred_mask = tf.cast(pred_mask,dtype=tf.float32)
    model=Model(input_img,[pred_mask,rpn_bbox_pred,rpn_cls_score,rpn_cls_prob,feat_map_shape],name='unet_rpn')
    return model
```

And here is a skeleton of the training loop:

```
unet_rpn=get_UNet_RPN(params)
unet_rpn.summary()

optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

for epoch in range(0,epochs):
    #Shuffle training data
    np.random.shuffle(train_i)
    #Iterate through each image 
    for i in train_i:
        with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
            tape.watch(unet_rpn.trainable_variables)
            # forward pass through the unet/rpn
            y_pred, bbox_pred, cls_pred, cls_prob, feat_map_shape = unet_rpn(i)

            # Generate region proposals
            ...
            # Calculate loss
            loss=...
                                             
        grads=tape.gradient(loss,unet_rpn.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,unet_rpn.trainable_variables))
```

My perusal of the docs have unearthed many reasons why all the gradients might return "None" (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff) but none of them make sense to me, as my loop basically follows the structure of the one in the docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try 'grads=tape.gradient(loss,unet_rpn.trainable_variables)' instead of 'grads=tape.gradient(loss,unet_rpn.trainable_weights)'

Comment: I did try both, they both produced the same error, unfortunately. Thanks!